# A regex which detects symbol " (quotes) in the text avoiding it inside tags <>

Tags: regex

I need a regex which detects symbol " (quotes) that is located in a text but if it is located inside tags (e.g `<a href="https://bla-bla">` ) it should be okay.

In other words, regex should find quotes (") in the text but if it is inside tags `<>`, it should avoid it. I have a regex which detects quotes inside tags **`<[a-zA-Z\s]+="[\w:\/\.]+">`** but I cannot come up with a regex which detects quotes in the text avoiding it if it is located inside tags.

I would appreciate any help or ideas... Thanks.

Comment: [`<[^<>]*>(*SKIP)(?!)|"`](https://regex101.com/r/6ccgRa/1). But really, if you are dealing with a mark-up document, use the appropriate parser instead of running a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...  That's what I do.  This is 1.5 years of work-ola.  This reg-ex has been tested (in use, by me) for almost a year.  It works...  basically... Note: there is one case which is not really a bug, but is debatable.... It will not match an attribute that is worded as such: `<A HREF = "http://url.com/dir..">` ***where there is a space between the equals and the attribute-value***.  Note the WHITESPACE-EQUALS-WHITESPACE pattern....  It is easily modified, but not proper HTML.

I hope this answers the question you have asked, if not - please comment.  I think you are asking about retrieving attributes out of HTML tags.  Correct?  Your reg-ex looked exactly at what I stared at for a long time... :)

Here is how to retrieve an HTML attribute-value:

```
public static final Pattern P3 = Pattern.compile(   "("                     +
                                                     "[\\w-]+=\"[^\"]*?\""   + "|" +
                                                     "[\\w-]+='[^']*?'"      + "|" +
                                                     "[\\w-]+=[\\w-]*"       + "|" +
                                                     "[\\w-]+"               + "|" +
                                                     "\\s+"                  + "|" +
                                                     "[^>]+"                 + ")",
                                                     Pattern.DOTALL  );
```

Here's the HTML matcher regex... (not part of answering your question, I hope you don't mind!)

```
public static final Pattern P1 = Pattern.compile
  ("<\\/?(\\w+)"                          +
      "(?:"   +   "[\\w-]+=\"[^\"]*?\""   + "|"   // attribute="any valid string, without (the same) quote"
              +   "[\\w-]+='[^']*?'"      + "|"   // attribute='any valid string without (the same) quote'
              +   "[\\w-]+=[\\w-]*"       + "|"   // attribute=any-valid-string-no-spaces-or-punctuation-etc
              +   "[\\w-]+"               + "|"   // attribute
              +   "\\s+"                  + "|"   // any white-space
              +   "[^>]+"                 + ")*"  // Any miscellaneous characters ("Junk?"), *EXCEPT* a "greater-than"
                                                  // (MUST be THE LAST or-option)
                                                  //      NOTE: The above "|" (or-branch), *MUST* be at the end... or else
                                                  //            It will match everything, (except '>'), and miss the whole point.
                                                  //            (Specifically, the first three attribute-value pair clauses are
                                                  //             how to avoid the greater-than-within-tag problem!!!  
      + "\\/?>",                                  // Ending-HTML-Tag symbol is a "greater-than" or "slash-greater-than"
      Pattern.DOTALL  );
```